# vlc - video and playlist simultaneously like windows media player

Tags: vlc-media-player, playlists

I like a lot of the features that offers VLC player but i didn't achieve to have see eithrt the video and the playlist in the same window, and without the library folders, only the video and the playlist. Any solutions to that?

Comment: VLC can use downloadable [skins](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/4i2tro/best_vlc_skinvlc_alternative_for_touch_use/?st=jcl5mx5y&sh=fccee43f). I've never tried them, so I don't know whether they can fix your issue or not.

Comment: but if i use i skin i suppose i will lose all the hotkeys no? anyways there should be a solution for something that simple, i don't know. The think is i like the default skin of the VLC, i only want that functionality.

Comment: @akerbelz I've never tried to customize VLC's default interface, but I have been greatly disappointed by trying to manage my music library with it. [Banshee](http://banshee.fm) is the best for such, even superior to iTunes. The website might be down atm, but the project is [still active](https://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/). :-/